# Add iterations of output integers

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript

```
i = 0
while i <= 1000
  console.log i  if i % 3 is 0
  console.log i  if i % 5 is 0
  i++
```

I want to add each output of `i` together. i.e. `0+0+3+5+6+9+10...+1000`

Is there an algorithm to do this in coffeescript, or do I just start adding every single one of these numbers together?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the well known sum-of-integers formula?

```
Sum(1 to n) = n(n+1)/2
```

It looks like you want the sum of integers that are multiples of 3 plus the sum of integers that are a multiple of 5. (Do you also need to remove excess multiples of 15?)  Once you have figured out how many there are of each `<=1000`, it's just a matter of scaling the above formula.  While this is more of a mathematical problem than a programming one, the Coffeescript shell would be a convenient calculator.

Of course it would be good idea to test the result against the brute force (simple summation).

I just tested both methods.  Speed is not an issue with either.